# Mailing shows white gap between images

Tags: image, newsletter, mailing

On the website Ymlp.com I've designed a newsletter. Two images are below each other, but in Outlook (2007) there is a small white gap between them. Gmail, Hotmail and Thunderbird don't have this problem. On http://www.yn5.nl/2b-xcl/mailing/map/witregel.jpg you can see the problem.
This is the mailing: http://www.yn5.nl/2b-xcl/mailing/map/view.html

How to remove the white space?

Answer (score 0):

You need `display:block;` in the style tag of your images